# How to avoid looping expect when asserting on stdout from child

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, child-process

I'm trying to write an integration test in Jest with TypeScript for a logging utility that has some logic and wraps [Gulp Fancy Log](https://github.com/gulpjs/fancy-log). I can't use Jest's `spyOn` with `console` (no `stdout` event occurs on the spy), I think because fancy log [resets](https://github.com/gulpjs/fancy-log/blob/0000c933753da4f690675274929a887ffc31dc25/index.js#L49) `console.log`.

My approach is to spawn a fixture to test the logging utility with `ts-node`, and then subscribe to the `data` event of the child process `stdout` stream. But it's called twice, first with fancy log's work and second with the param provided to log:

```js
test('prints a string given to the logging function', done => {
  const loggerInstance = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'logger_string_param.ts')
  const sut = spawn('ts-node', [loggerInstance])

  sut.stdout.on('data', data => {
    // can't expect here, it's called twice, first with `[16:41:50]`
    // or similar and then with `something happened`
    console.log(data.toString())
  })

  sut.on('exit', () => done())
})
```

And the fixture:

```js
import { log } from '../utils'

log(`something happened`)
```

I would like to assert inside the `data` event listener, in the order the assertion is called (e.g. different assertions for first and second call). How can I do that (or refactor my test to achieve it)?

Comment: you dont't need to spin child process for that, just create new stream (in memory or file stream) and pass it as stdout file descriptor for your logger.

Comment: @bogdanoff thank you. I also realized in this case, I can use Node's `exec` instead of `spawn`, and have a callback to work in instead of dealing with streams. I'm still interested in how to assert against stream output from spawn, I can see other situations I'd want to do that.

Comment: yes and for asserting inside stream, I think you should wrap that process in Promise, like error event & assertion error leads to calling rejection callback (w/ destroying process)   & close event for resolve, ???